# php DOMDocument line of table to text

Tags: php, html, html-table, domdocument

I got the following:

```
$table      = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(1);
$row        = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('td');
```

I would like to get a array with the textContent of all the td elements into an array.

I could manually do this using something like

```
foreach ($row as $col) {
            $array[] = $col->textContent;
}
```

But I am sure there must be a function how to automatically do this.

Comment: can you show what output you are getting?

Comment: No output? There is nothing outputting anything... But if a do a var_dump of $array then i get a array("text1", "text2" ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no PHP-function to do this!

My self-programmed function to achieve this looks like this:

```
function elementsToArray($elements) {
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $array[] = $element->textContent;
}
return $array;
}
```